# CSS: What happens when declaring 2 id selectors on the same line

Tags: css

while doing some research i saw the following piece of code in the CSS file:

```
#element1{
overflow: hidden;     
width: 880px;
height: 32px;
padding: 5px 30px;
background: #c82c74;
border-bottom: 1px solid #870843;}

#element1 #element2{ 
float: left;
width: 400px;
padding-right: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}
```

As you can see the ID of element1 has its own set of properties and values then it is used again alongside element2. In the corresponding HTML file this is how the following styles were implemented:

```
<div id="element1">
<div id="element2">
</div>
</div>
```

What does this piece of code mean and what is being achieved here?

Comment: don't you have a monitor? No Offence. Try it and see :)

Comment: #element1 #element2 means that the element2 div is inside element1 and so the priority of being used #element2 is greater than #element1 #element2

Answer (score 4):

`#element1 #element2` means it is only styling the element that has an id of `element2` that is inside an element that has an id of `element1`

If you want to style both elements with the same style then you would need to add a comma between the elements: `#element1, #element2`

People would use `#element1 #element2` say if they wanted to override specific styles for `element2` but only if it is in `element1` - for example, say `element2` is on all your web pages and we have the following styles:

```
#element2 {width:800px;}
```

now if you had a particular page where you only wanted it to be 400px wide you could qualify the selector to a higher level to override that element on the certain page - so say we gave the body tag an id of `element1` for that specific page, adding

```
#element1 #element2 {width:400px;}
```

would mean that `element2` would be 400px for that page and then 800px on all other pages

Comment: yep - Called scoping or localized css as well

Comment: @SachinShanbhag actually scoping is where you include `<style scope>` tags within the element you want to style, the above is just about css specificity

Answer (score 2):

That last selection you made, `#element1 #element2` will tell CSS to look for a child of `#element1` that has an id of `#element2` but when using IDs you mostly don't need to do that because IDs are used to uniquely define an object although you may use classes for these type of selection or `scoping` objects.

See some [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) for [Scoping](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/).

Comment: Though it's possible to have something unique on a page, without being unique across the site.

Comment: But you're writing your stylesheet to apply to the whole site, right? So let's say that you want to style a banner image with a border on the homepage, but without a border on subsequent pages. This banner image has an ID `heroImage`. Your homepage has an ID on the body of `homepage`. Would you not style this using `#homepage #heroImage`, to specifically target the image on this template?

Comment: NP, feel free to up-vote my answer below where I'd said the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

These styles for `#element2` will only get applied when it occurs within an `#element1`.

For instance if `element1` was an ID used for the homepage & `element2` for a search box, the searchbox on the homepage would use these styles, but searchboxes elsewhere wouldn't (e.g. on a page with `<body id="contentpage">`).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if you'll write `#element2` instead of `#element1 #element2` there will be no change, but in my example:

```
<div class="class_one">
<div class="class_two"></div>
</div>
<div class="class_two"></div>
```

CSS Example 1 - You will see 3 squares
http://jsfiddle.net/BCq9C/

```
.class_one {
background: red;
padding: 10px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}

.class_two {
background: blue;
padding: 10px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

CSS Example 2nd - You will see only 2 squares
http://jsfiddle.net/8aDTB/

```
.class_one {
background: red;
padding: 10px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}

.class_one .class_two {
background: blue;
padding: 10px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: If you both use `#element2 { ... }` and `#element1 #element2 { ...}` in the stylesheet to style `#element2`, the last one will be overruling since it's more specific [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/whaQb/).

Answer (score -1):

`#element1 #element2` will style the unique element `#element2` inside the unique element `#element1`

But since an `id` is unique, it is completely useless to do it that way.
Using `#element2` is enough.